# WUA API unable to uninstall updates

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, com, windows-update

I have encountered an issue when using Windows Update Agent (WUA) API.

Whenever I try to uninstall an update using `IUpdateInstaller.IsForced := True;
IUpdateInstaller.BeginUninstall(...` i'm getting `WU_E_UNINSTALL_NOT_ALLOWED` (*The update could not be uninstalled because the request did not originate from a WSUS server*). Does it mean that I can't use WUA API to uninstall updates? In that case, why are BeginUninstall/Uninstall methods there?

Comment: It seems you have two different questions here. You should ask two separate questions as such. SO is a one-question-one-accepted-answer site.

Comment: OK, I edited the post, leaving the more important question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Hey, Scripting Guy! How Can I Remove a Microsoft Update?](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2009/03/12/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-remove-a-microsoft-update/) (and also [here](http://help.wuinstall.com/en/WuInstall.html?BasicOptions.html)) the WUA API can only be used to uninstall updates that were installed by a WSUS server.

You might be able to use DISM instead, e.g., see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825265.aspx) and [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825010.aspx).  (Note that Windows updates are refered to as "packages" in DISM terminology.)