# WUA API unable to find update

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2008, patch, wuapi

Code sample:

```
$UpdateSession = New-Object -ComObject 'Microsoft.Update.Session'

$UpdateSearcher = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$Updates = $UpdateSearcher.Search('IsInstalled=1')

$Updates | Where-Object { $_.Title -like '*KB2506143*' }
```

I'm trying to uninstall WMF3 programmatically, but I keep getting errors when trying to utilize wusa.exe,

```
wusa /uninstall /kb:2506143 /quiet /norestart /log:C:\log.evt
```

> CbsClient::CbsClient.00110: Failed to create a CBS session instance
>   CbsClient::CbsClient.00127: Exit with error code 0X80040154 (Class not registered)
>   UninstallWorker.00664: Start of search
>   CbsClient::OpenPackageByKB.00268: CBS session is not initialized.
>   CbsClient::OpenPackageByKB.00320: Exit with error code 0X8000ffff (Catastrophic failure)
>   UninstallWorker.00667: Failed: OpenPackageByKB() for KB2506143
>   UninstallWorker.00799: Exit with error code 0X8000ffff (Catastrophic failure)
>   RebootIfRequested.01446: Reboot is not scheduled. IsRunWizardStarted: 0, IsRebootRequired: 0, RestartMode: 1
>   Windows update  could not be uninstalled because of error 2147549183 "Catastrophic failure" (Command line: "`C:\windows\System32\wusa.exe  /uninstall /kb:2506143 /quiet /norestart /log:C:\log.evt`")
>   wWinMain.01962: Failed to uninstall update ; Error: 0X8000ffff, Catastrophic failure. Command line: `C:\windows\System32\wusa.exe  /uninstall /kb:2506143 /quiet /norestart /log:C:\log.evt`
>   wWinMain.01998: Exit with error code 0X8000ffff (Catastrophic failure)

so I'm pursuing using the WUA API.  The above code snippet gives me a `$Null` return, but I can use `Get-Hotfix -ID KB2506143` or `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_QuickFixEngineering -Filter 'HotFixID="KB2506143"'` to find the update.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38936202/wua-api-unable-to-uninstall-updates) is similar, but it's getting access denied when trying to uninstall the patch after it has already been found, while my question is: **how do I find the patch in the first place?**

I'm not sure how the patch got applied, so if I run into the same issue once I find it, I have [that resolution](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2009/03/12/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-remove-a-microsoft-update/) at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the purpose of all this was to upgrade to WMF5.1 programmatically and I found a workaround for what I was trying to accomplish.  PowerShell v3 was enabled in the OS using DISM during the build process and cannot be removed by WUA because it wasn't placed there by WUA.

---

Workaround 1:

```
dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellV3
```

This downgrades `$PSVersionTable` to `v2`, but it does not remove the patch `KB2506143`.  This causes the need to uninstall it through the UI manually still so it didn't really accomplish what I need.

---

Workaround 2:

WMF3 cannot be upgraded to WMF5, but it **can** be upgraded to WMF4, then WMF5(.1).

Ultimately, I installed WMF4 over WMF3 with `wusa.exe` while still disabling v3 in dism for good measure and was successful installing WMF5.1 over WMF4 after a reboot (again, with `wusa.exe`).

The limitation is rooted with the WUA not being able to manage patches that it did not install (through a `.msu` or WSUS)